# Вычисление корней многочлена в Mathcad

Tags: полином

Подскажите, как в Mathcad вычислить все корни многочлена, например,
4x^4 + 8x - 3 = 0?

Заранее всем благодарен.

Comment: @bomba868, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @bomba868, инструкция как узнать: http://bit.ly/1ASnZFM

Answer (score 1):

Там имеется функция polyroots(v), где v - вектор коэффициентов полинома.